# How to pass JSON data as parameters in JavaScript function while data appending to the div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-4

jQuery + JavaScript + Rails 4

```
prefix = "onward_"

json_data = {"367278": 
               {"bus_schedules": 
                  { "id": 367278,
                    "origin_id": 134,
                    "destination_id": 506
                  },
                "drop_points": null,
                "board_points": null,
                "operator_name": "ABC"
                }
             }

json_data1 = JSON.stringify(json_data);

html = '<a href="#" id="'+prefix+'active_travel_filter_'+
       operator_ids[i]
       +'"onclick="removeTravelFilter('
       +'\''+prefix+'\''+',\'travels\''+',\''
       +json_data1+'\',\''+json_data1+'\')" 

   value="'+operator_ids[i]+'">'
           +getOperatorName[operator_ids[i]]+'</a>'

console.log(html);

$("#active_fiters_blk").append(html);
```

//console.log output

```html
<a href="#" id="onward_active_travel_filter_90" onclick="removeTravelFilter('onward_','travels','{"367278":{"bus_schedules":{"id":367278,"origin_id":134,"destination_id":506},"drop_points":null,"board_points":null,"operator_name":"ABC"}}','{"367278":{"bus_schedules":{"id":367278,"origin_id":134,"destination_id":506},"drop_points":null,"board_points":null,"operator_name":"ABC"}}')" value="90">ABC</a>
```

But while append to the `div` I am getting this format, but it should be above format.

```html
<a value="33" group)"}}')"="" group)"}}','{"367278":{"bus_schedules":{"id":367278,"origin_id":134,"destination_id":506},"drop_points":null,"board_points":null,"operator_name":"sre="" booking(ananth="" 367278":{"bus_schedules":{"id":367278,"origin_id":134,"destination_id":506},"drop_points":null,"board_points":null,"operator_name":"sre="" onclick="removeTravelFilter('onward_','travels','{" id="onward_active_travel_filter_33" href="#">ABC</a>
```

It should be an inline script only because I want each individual `onclick` event.

Comment: Why do you want/need to store it as a data attribute? That's usually for transferring data from the server.

Comment: I need to pass full json_data to another js function there i will validate the things.

Comment: Don't use inline event handlers or build your UI with HTML strings. Create proper DOM elements and use JavaScript to bind the event handler. Then you don't even have to convert the data to JSON. Your current approach will only make it more difficult for your to make changes later on. To learn more about event handlers, see http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html. To learn more about the DOM: http://quirksmode.org/dom/intro.html. And since you are using jQuery, you probably also profit from reading the jQuery tutorial: https://learn.jquery.com/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The HTML you're trying to insert, is this string:

```html
<a href="#" id="onward_active_travel_filter_0" onclick="removeTravelFilter('onward_','travels','{"367278":{"bus_schedules":{"id":367278,"origin_id":134,"destination_id":506},"drop_points":null,"board_points":null,"operator_name":"SRE Booking(Ananth Group)"}}','{"367278":{"bus_schedules":{"id":367278,"origin_id":134,"destination_id":506},"drop_points":null,"board_points":null,"operator_name":"SRE Booking(Ananth Group)"}}')" value="0">0</a>
```

When you place that into the DOM, your browser will be confused by the parameters of the `onclick` part: `onclick="removeTravelFilter('onward_','travels','{"` That last quote (`"`) there will be interpreted as the end of the `onclick` parameter.

If you switch around the quotes in your JavaScript like this:

```
html = "<a href='#' id='"+prefix+"active_travel_filter_"+operator_ids[i]+"' onclick='removeTravelFilter("+"\""+prefix+"\""+",\"travels\""+","+json_data1+","+json_data1+")' value='"+operator_ids[i]+"'>"+getOperatorName[operator_ids[i]]+"</a>"
```

Then you should be fine:

```html
<a href='#' id='onward_active_travel_filter_0' onclick='removeTravelFilter("onward_","travels",{"367278":{"bus_schedules":{"id":367278,"origin_id":134,"destination_id":506},"drop_points":null,"board_points":null,"operator_name":"SRE Booking(Ananth Group)"}},{"367278":{"bus_schedules":{"id":367278,"origin_id":134,"destination_id":506},"drop_points":null,"board_points":null,"operator_name":"SRE Booking(Ananth Group)"}})' value='0'>0</a>
```

I'm not saying this is the best way to pass those parameters to your function, but it works.

Comment: SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list is coming....

...moveTravelFilter("onward_","travels","{"367278":{"bus_schedules":{"id":367278,"o...

Comment: @user3410226: Oh, looks like I made a little mistake in the code, can you try again? I edited my answer's code.

Comment: Yes Its working, but you are talking about best practice...can you tell me best practice for this

Comment: @user3410226: Best practice would be to store the json in a JavaScript variable, and to reference that variable in the function call, something like: `onclick='removeTravelFilter("onward_", "travels", myJson, myJson)`

Answer (score 0):

I'd maintain a dictionary associating anchor id names with their corresponding json data.

```
window.dataCache = {
   "onward_active_travel_filter_90": {...},
   ...
}
```

Once element clicked I'll fetch the required json object.

```
$('a').click(function(){
   var id = this.id;
   var jsd = dataCache[id];
   //pass to target function
   foo(jsd);
});
```

Now if the anchor is added a little late into the page dom, I'd have to take care about attaching event handlers appropriately.

In jquery, we can just work with the [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) handler.

Explanation:

Well, we normally do something like `$('element').click(function(){...});`. This is usually executed in the jquery dom ready event:

```
$(function(){
    $('element').click(function(){...});
});
```

The stretch of code in the dom ready event is executed once the DOM is ready for jquery consumption. Hence the click event will get attached to any `element` that exists in the DOM at that point of time.

Any subsequent addition of `element` into the web page, the click event handler will not get attached to it.

But we'd want such a functionality!

Hence we have to manually take care of it. Meaning create the `element` wire the event click handler appropriately, and then add it to DOM.

An alternative to this we have the jQuery `.on()` method. However, it functions differently from whats is described above. It listens for the click event which "bubbles" up on a target container.

Please read the docs of `.on()` to get a better idea.

Comment: i am new to javascript and jquery can you elaborate please.

Comment: This json_data is coming from the previous js function. there it is coming from the rails view.html.erb by <%= raw json_data.to_json %>.....right.

Comment: So that bit of code you've written is in a kind of for-loop? When is it called?

Comment: Yes i tried this .on function but you know i am appending a link, when i am clicking on the link it is taking always last id....but i want onclick event on every link....right

Comment: Hi. What is that `operator_ids` variable?